Issues with Converting BIN to Bootable ISO for OS Development
I'm developing an OS and have been using a BIN file that contains both my bootloader and kernel. I’ve been running the BIN file using QEMU with the -drive option, and everything works as expected. However, now I want to load the OS onto real hardware and have created an ISO from the BIN file using the following command:
xorriso -as mkisofs \
  -b io_os.bin \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 \
  -boot-info-table \
  -o bin/io_os.iso bin/io_os.bin

When I try to boot from the ISO, it fails to load the kernel. When I inspect the ISO with a hexdump, I see thousands of lines filled with zeros. I suspect there might be an issue with the way the bootloader and kernel are structured within the ISO, but I’m not sure what exactly is wrong.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and suggest a way to fix it?

Is your io_os.bin in any way prepared for getting patched by a
boot info table which overwrites bytes 8 to 63 ?
If not, then omit option -boot-info-table .
If not the size of io_os.bin is 2048 bytes and it is not prepared
for a boot info table, then omit option -boot-load-size 4 .
If your .bin is actually a disk image, then try what happens if
you omit option -no-emul-boot to get floppy emulation, or if you
replace it by option -hard-disk-boot to get hard disk emulation.
You will probably need to read the El Torito Bootable CD-ROM
Specification. Wikipedia points to:
https://web.archive.org/web/20080218195330/http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/specscdrom.pdf

Edit after first comment by Ioane Baidoshvili:
I am not an expert for boot loaders and there is not much documentation
about how to create a boot image for legacy x86 BIOS.
OSDev.org could be a place to gain knowledge:
https://wiki.osdev.org/El-Torito
https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones
The latter proposes GRUB as bootloader and grub-mkrescue as frontend
of xorriso for creating the bootable ISO. I.e. to use the GRUB El Torito
for platform "i386-pc".
This here looks like it has provisions for -boot-info-table and thus
might be a central part of GRUB's "eltorito.img":
https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/boot/i386/pc/cdboot.S#n48
Similarly with SYSLINUX/ISOLINUX in line 178 of:
https://github.com/geneC/syslinux/blob/master/core/isolinux.asm
Some sparse hints about the emulations and non-emulation of legacy BIOS
can be found in section 5 of El Torito, "CD Boot Procedures".

Thanks for answering my question but it still doesn't seem to work. I got rid of -boot-info-table and that made it more organized because I didn't do any preparations for boot info tables. I split io_os.bin into bootloader.bin and kernel.bin, fed bootloader.bin into -b in mkisofs but it still doesn't work. I specify the sector it should start from with isoinfo -i iso/io_os.iso and get the number of sectors from the linker. I'm new with generating ISOs so please bare with me if I haven't clarified any needed details. If you can help me please and thank you!
